# simple push notification but its not working and its throwing an error

Tags: flutter

im trying to display a push notification by clicking a text button but then it throws this error i tried to search but couldnt fix it, i tried reinstalling the app and also restarted the app multiple times

```
E/flutter ( 8853):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
E/flutter ( 8853):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/flutter ( 8853):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
E/flutter ( 8853):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
E/flutter ( 8853):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter ( 8853):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
E/flutter ( 8853):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
E/flutter ( 8853): )
E/flutter ( 8853): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope
package:flutter/…/services/message_codecs.dart:653
E/flutter ( 8853): #1      MethodChannel.\_invokeMethod
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:296
E/flutter ( 8853): \<asynchronous suspension\>
E/flutter ( 8853): #2      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show
package:flutter_local_notifications/src/flutter_local_notifications_plugin.dart:234
E/flutter ( 8853): \<asynchronous suspension\>
E/flutter ( 8853):
```

```
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

class NotificationApi {
  static final _notification = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  static Future _notificationDetails() async {
    return const NotificationDetails(
      android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'channel id'
            'channel name',
        'channel description',
        importance: Importance.high,
      ),
      iOS: DarwinNotificationDetails(),
    );
  }

  static Future showNotification({
    int id = 0,
    String? title,
    String? body,
    String? payload,
  }) async =>
      _notification.show(id, title, body, await _notificationDetails(),
          payload: payload);
}
```

```
flutter_local_notifications: ^12.0.3+1
```

Comment: Hope you are not using an emulator

Comment: Is this the whole error message?